# android : Opening a file from the list of files listed in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I am working on a project which displays the list of the files from a directory in the SD card. All the files that I have displayed are .xls files. I have an XLS reader in my mobile phone and I want to open the file that is clicked in the listview. Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subjects_list);

        final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
        subjectslistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.subjectslistview);
        addSubjectbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.subjectslistfabutton);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
        subjectslistview.setAdapter(adapter);
        subjectslistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    //attempt to connect to SD card
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/SPAMS excel files";
    File dir = new File(path);

    File files[] = dir.listFiles();
    for(int i =0; i < files.length; i++){
        fileList.add(files[i].getName());
    }

    addSubjectbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.startAnimation(myAnim);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am touched.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent goto_addsubj = new Intent(SubjectsListActivity.this,
                            AddSubjectActivity.class);
                    startActivity(goto_addsubj);
                    finish();
                }
            }, 130);

        }
    });


}

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

        TextView temp = (TextView) view;
        Toast.makeText(this, temp.getText() + " " + position,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

I am hoping for your help guys! Please help me. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is launch the XLS reader with an intent (assuming the XLS reader has an intent you can launch with).

When the item is clicked, grab the uri to the file, and launch the intent.

```
Uri uri = new Uri(path);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel");

try {
    startActivity(intent);
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "No Application Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response @Jeff Houghton. One thing i need to ask, in the line,
`Uri uri = new Uri(path);`
what is the "path" you are referring to?

Comment: The path should be the path to the specific file you want to open with the XLS reader.